# Searching for incomplete fields

Tags: custom-search

Is it possible to search for a list of records for which a specific field has not been completed?  For example, if the options in the custom field are 'yes' or 'no', is it possible to find which records have not had either of these selected?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use the Search builder : Menu `search -> Search builder`.

Then you can choose the record type, the field and most important the **operator** : you have `empty` or `is null` (not defined) which should work for your need.